# How to properly clear pending External Interrupt in LPC17xx?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, lpc

I am writing an program for the LPC1768 that simulates a state machine. In the beginning states the program must be able to handle button interrupts (EINT1 EINT2). Then interrupts are disabled on the NVIC (Nested Vector Interrupt Controller) but are still sent to it, becoming pending. If I re-enable the interrupts they are handled, so i tried to clear the pending ones before doing that. It solves the problem but then new interrupts aren't seen anymore by the NVIC and I don't understand why.

I disable interrupt using:

```
NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT2_IRQn);
NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
```

when it's time I clear pending ones and re-enable:

```
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EINT2_IRQn);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT2_IRQn);
NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
```

The code was not executed on the board but only debugged using the keil uvision5 software.

Comment: Code you are showing is general for ARM-Cortex-M CPUs. If you clear pending bit in NVIC, there is still possibility that your peripheral sets it again, so make sure that you also clear all peripheral bits.

Comment: @tilz0R Hi, the problem is not that the pending bit i re-set, in fact it isn't. the problem is that interrupts from the peripheral are not seen anymore by the nvic

Comment: Did you disable global interrupts using `__disable_irq()` function? If so, enable back with `__enable_irq()`.

Comment: i didn't do that because i also use a timer and i need to handle its interrupts. And those work even if the buttons don't

Comment: Then focus on EINT peripheral and GPIO configuration. Code you posted looks ok.

Comment: I'll look more into it, but i never change the configuration of the peripheral in the code after its initialization.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "The code was not executed on the board but only debugged using the keil uvision5 software." ???  You should probably try running it on the hardware *without* the debugger and using some other means of output, to verify that it isn't an issue with either a simulator or interaction between the debugger and interrupts.